# How to set a limit for nested field in AWS amplify DynamoDB schema on my React App?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify and DynamoDB and I would like to set a limit from a the nested field "medias". This is the query on AppSync to get only 4 items :

```
{
  getUser(id: "xxx4e5b-9704-564xxx") {
    medias(limit: 4) {
      items {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems to work, this is the result I have on AppSync :

```
{
  "data": {
    "getUser": {
      "medias": {
        [
          {
            "title": "Test 1"
          },
          {
            "title": "Test Audio"
          },
          {
            "title": "Test Guitare"
          },
          {
            "title": "Test lien"
          }
        ],
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to know how to do this query on my React application ? I tried this but it didn't work (I should have 4 media items in my response but I get more) :

```
const query = await API.graphql(
        graphqlOperation(getUser, {
          id: userID,
          medias: { limit: 4 }
        })
      )
```

I didn't find any help on amplify doc. Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with the way you pass the parameters in to `graphqlOperation` which takes in a query and the options for that query only.

```
const limit = 4;
// whatever you want to filter by
const filter = {id: userID};

const result = await API.graphql(
  graphqlOperation(getUser, {filter, limit})
);
```